# Mongoose Schema values not being saved to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**I'm trying to associate User schema with Blog schema so that I can authorize user permissions for only blog post owner to only be able to edit/delete blog post. Im able to get the author field {id, username} into my create route to store in my DB, but not the other values.**

*mongoose blog schema*

```
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  author: {
    id:{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user"
    },
  username: String,
}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("blog", blogSchema);
```

*mongoose user schema*

```
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

*blog.js routes*

```
const express        = require("express");
const bodyParser     = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser   = require("cookie-parser");
const mongoose       = require("mongoose");
const router         = express.Router();
const blog           = require("../models/blog");
const user           = require("../models/user");
const objectId       = require("mongodb");
const middleware     = require("../middleware");
const expressSanitizer = require("express-sanitizer");




//INDEX ROUTE//
router.get("/", function(req,res){
  blog.find({}, function(err, blog){
  if(err){
  res.redirect("/home");
  }else{
  res.render("blog/index", {blog:blog});

  }
  })
  });


//NEW ROUTE//
router.get("/new", middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
      res.render("blog/new");
  });
```

**Not getting title or content values passed into newBlog in blog.create below. When I console.log newlyCreated it just has the MongoDB object _id, created, and author object with id: and username. Therefore can't access these values on the show page template**

```
//CREATE ROUTE//
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
  var created = req.body.created;
  var author  = {
    id: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.username
  };
  var title   = req.body.title;
  var content = req.body.content;
  var newBlog = {created:created, author:author, title:title, content:content}

  req.body.blog.content = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.content)
  blog.create(newBlog, function(err, newlyCreated){
            if (err){
              console.log(err);
              res.status(404).render("404");
            }else{
              console.log(newlyCreated);
              req.flash("success", "New Blog Created!")
            res.redirect("/blog");
  }
  })
  });


    //EDIT ROUTE//
  router.get("/:_id/edit", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    blog.findById(req.params, function(err, foundBlog){
      if(err){
            res.status(404).render("404");
          }else{
      res.render("blog/edit", {blog:foundBlog});
    }
    })
    });


//SHOW ROUTE//
router.get("/:_id", function(req, res){

  blog.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id) ,function (err, blog){
    if(err){
        res.status(404).render("404");
    }else{
      res.render("blog/show", {blog: blog});

  }
})
});


//UPDATE ROUTE//
router.put("/:_id", function(req,res){
  req.body.blog.content = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.content)
  blog.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id), req.body.blog, function(err, updatedBlog){
  console.log(req.body)
    if(err){
          res.status(404).render("404");
    }else{
          req.flash("success", "Blog Successfully Updated!")
          res.redirect("/blog/"+req.params._id);
  }
})
  });

//DELETE ROUTE//
router.delete("/:_id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
  blog.findByIdAndRemove(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id), function(err){
  if(err){
  req.flash("error", "Blog Not Removed!")
  res.redirect("/blog")
  }else{
  req.flash("success", "Blog Successfully Deleted!")
  res.redirect("/blog")
}
})
  });



module.exports = router;
```

*app.js file*

```
const express          = require("express"),
      app              = express(),
      bodyParser       = require("body-parser"),
      mongoose         = require("mongoose"),
      methodOverride   = require("method-override"),
      moment           = require("moment"),
      flash            = require("connect-flash"),
      blog             = require("./models/blog"),
      user             = require("./models/user"),
      passport         = require("passport"),
      localStrategy    = require("passport-local"),
      session          = require("express-session"),
      cookieParser     = require("cookie-parser"),
      expressSanitizer = require("express-sanitizer"),
      router           = express.Router();



//Requiring Routes
const indexRoutes      = require("./routes/index");
const  homeRoutes      = require("./routes/home");
const  aboutRoutes     = require("./routes/about");
const  blogRoutes      = require("./routes/blog");
const  bookRoutes      = require("./routes/book");

//Connect to DB
const databaseUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/fitness_app";
mongoose.connect(databaseUri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err){
  if (err){
    console.log ("Error connecting to Mongo DB")
  }else{
    console.log("Connected to Mongo DB")
  }
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views, views");
app.use(express.static(__dirname,/public/));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());


app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localStrategy(user.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(user.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(user.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
  next();
});

app.use("/", indexRoutes);
app.use("/home", homeRoutes);
app.use("/about", aboutRoutes);
app.use("/blog", blogRoutes);
app.use("/book", bookRoutes);


app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.status(404).render("404");
});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log("Server Has Started!");
});
```

*new blog.ejs*

```
<%- include ("../partials/header-blog-new") %>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="top"  class="row justify-content-around">
      <h2> <i class=""></i>New Blog Post<i class=""></i></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div id="outer">
          <form class="form-group" action="/blog" method="POST">
            <div class="">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blog[title]">Title:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="blog[title]" placeholder="Title">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="blog[content]">Content:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="blog[content]"placeholder="Blog Away" rows="8" width="50%"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn form-control" name="Connect">Submit!</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you try to console req.body.title and req.body.content ? before saving them in db

Comment: Im getting undefined, from console.log(newBlog) for those parameters